# What is more efficient to read from a text file, File or FileReader?

Tags: java, performance, input, inputstream

I am a bit confused at the difference between the file and FileReader classes in Java, they both work for me in the same way in that they can take a text file and input it into an array but which one is actually more efficient to use and which is the best to use in a situation like this.

I am aware questions like this have been asked but they tend to focus on specific code or the methods which the two classes have.

Thank you.

Comment: what do you mean by "file" do you mean FileInputStream?

Comment: Can you paste the code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

---

[`java.io.File`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html) represents the file itself - its existence, whether it's a file or directory, its last modified date, etc. You can't read the contents of a file with any of the methods in the `File` class.

However, you can use a `File` as the input to another class like [`java.io.FileReader`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FileReader.html), which then allows you to read the contents of the file.

Ultimately, the speed of reading text files comes down to what you want to do with them. Profile your code to see which method takes the longest. You could use `java.io.FileReader`, `java.util.Scanner` or even `java.nio.channels.FileChannel` in conjunction with a `java.nio.charset.CharsetDecoder`.

As you say you're reading text files, you should stick to classes for reading character streams, rather than ones which read raw bytes. This allows you to correctly read in more than just ASCII characters.

Answer (score 1):

In terms of memory efficiency FileInputStream is more efficient because it reads single bytes.  FileReader reads characters, which are four bytes each.

Source: http://nadeausoftware.com/articles/2008/02/java_tip_how_read_files_quickly#FileReaderandBufferedReader

Comment: Are you really arguing that `FileInputStream` is more 'efficient' than `FileReader` because `FileReader` returns a char (4-bytes) and not 1 byte at a time?  Or did I misunderstand?

Comment: FileReader converts the bytes into a character, so it uses more memory.

Comment: It might be *slower* as it has to interpret the characters from the bytes.  And it might use a *tiny* bit more memory (but swamped by any buffer you might - probably should - wrap it in, anyway).  I suppose it being slower might be relevant if doing something where you are not interested in the the content of the file (e.g. copying it).  Doesn't help much if you actually need to 'read' the content though.

Answer (score 1):

Use the `File` class to represent a file (i.e. a path to an existing file, or one you might be about to create).

Use `FileInputStream` (probably wrapping it in a `BufferedInputStream`) if you want to read bytes.

Use `FileReader` (probably wrapping it in a `BufferedReader`)  if you want to read characters (i.e. a text file, or similar).  You may want to specify the encoding (if you know it), or might prefer to rely on the system (OS) default encoding - that depends on your use case.

Also, where writing general utility methods prefer accepting just `InputStream` or `Reader`.  For example, `public static void copy(Reader r, Writer w) throws IOException` is more useful (reusable) than `public static void copy(FileReader r, FileWriter w) throws IOException`.  In general, only use a *specific* type when you can't use a more general abstraction (like `Reader`).